# Optimizing MySQL query where the number of returned rows is very large

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

Context:
We have a website where users(merchants) can add their apps/websites into the system and pay their users via API. Now, the problem comes when we have to show the list of those transactions to the merchant on their dashboard. Each merchant generates hundreds of transactions per second and on average merchants have like 2 million transactions per day and on the dashboard, we have to show today's stats to the merchant.

Main Problem:
We have to show today's transactions to the merchant which is around 2 million records for a single merchant.
So a query like this,

`SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user_id = 123 LIMIT 0,15`

Rows examined are 2 million in our example and that cannot be reduced in any way. The limit doesn't help here I think, because MySQL will still examine all rows an then pick first 15 from the result set.

How can we optimize queries like this where we have to show millions of records(with pagination of course) to the user?

**Edit:**

Explain output:

[image]

Query:

`explain select a.id, a.user_app_id, a.created_at, a.type, a.amount, a.currency_id, b.name, b.url from transactions as a left join user_apps as b on a.user_app_id = b.id where a.sender_user_id = ? and a.created_at BETWEEN '2020-03-20' AND '2020-03-21' order by a.created_at desc limit 15 offset 0`

Details:

Index `sender_user_id_2` is an composite index of `sender_user_id(int)` and `created_at(timestamp)` column.

This query is taking 5 to 15 seconds to return 15 rows.

If I run the same query for the sender_user_id which has only 24 transactions in the table, then the response in instant.

Comment: Do you need to show millions of records or would some form of summary do (i.e. totals per hour/minute) and a search for a particular user (in case of some query).

Comment: Need to show all the transactions, full list, searchable, sortable. The problem is if for example the user search for entries for today only, then the result set will be millions of rows, we can use pagination but still, query will have to go through all the records, right?

Comment: The requirement is inherently slow, so if that is what they really want (and they may find the reality is not as helpful as they thought) then just make sure you have indexes (and use ORDER BY to ensure consistency of rows retrieved).

Comment: Yes, I am already doing that, indexes are used correctly but the query takes 10+ seconds. I am trying to reduce that time.

Comment: The query you provided, and assuming you have an index on `user_id`, will read exactly 15 rows and stop. If this takes 10 seconds, you either do not have an index or this is not your query. Please provide your table structure, the actual query and the execution plan (write `explain ` infront of your query). As a rule of thumb: unless you export your data (including sending all your data to the app and let the app do everything in its memory), which is a one time thing where 10s are fine, you will never ever return millions of rows. As noone has the time to look at millions of rows.

Comment: I agree with Solarflare that something is strange.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE transactions` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`.  And the MySQL version number.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's fix what might be a bug:  You are including two midnights in that "day".  `BETWEEN` is "inclusive".

```
 AND  a.created_at BETWEEN '2020-03-20' AND '2020-03-21'
```

-->

```
 AND  a.created_at >= '2020-03-20'
 AND  a.created_at  < '2020-03-20' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

(There is no performance change, just the elimination of tomorrow's midnight.)

In your simple query, only 15 rows will be touched due to the `LIMIT`.  However, for more complex queries it may need to gather all rows, sort them, and only then peel off 15 rows.  The technique for preventing that inefficiency goes something like this:  Devise, if possible, an `INDEX` that handles all of the `WHERE` *and* the `ORDER BY`.

```
    where  a.sender_user_id = ?
      AND  a.created_at >= '2020-03-20'
      AND  a.created_at  < '2020-03-20' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    order by  a.created_at desc
```

needs `INDEX(sender_user_id, created_at)` -- in that order.  (And, in your query, nothing else encroaches on that.)

Pagination via `OFFSET` introduces another performance problem -- it must step over all `OFFSET` rows before getting the ones you want.  This is solvable by [remembering where you left off](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

So, why does `EXPLAIN` think it will hit a million rows?  Because Explain is dumb when it comes to handling `LIMIT`.  There is a [better way](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts) to estimate the effort.  That will show 15, not a million, if all is working well.  For `LIMIT 150, 15`, it will show 165.

You said "Index sender_user_id_2 is an composite index of sender_user_id(int) and created_at(timestamp) column."  Can you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can check for something else subtle going on?

Hmmm... I wonder if

```
order by  a.created_at desc
```

should be changed to match the index:

```
order by a.sender_user_id DESC, a.created_at desc
```

(What version of MySQL are you using?  I did some experimenting and found no difference because of having (or not) `sender_user_id` in the `ORDER BY.)

(Trouble -- It seems that the `JOIN` prevents the effective use of `LIMIT`.  Still digging...)

**New suggestion:**

```
select  a.id, a.user_app_id, a.created_at, a.type, a.amount, a.currency_id,
        b.name, b.url
    from  
    (
        SELECT  a1.id
            FROM  transactions as a1
            where  a1.sender_user_id = ?
              AND  a.created_at >= '2020-03-20'
              AND  a.created_at  < '2020-03-20' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
            order by  a1.created_at desc
            limit  15 offset 0 
    ) AS x
    JOIN  transactions AS a USING(id)
    left join  user_apps as b  ON x.user_app_id = b.id
```

This uses a generic 'trick' to move the `LIMIT` into a derived table, with minimal other stuff.  Then, with only 15 ids, the `JOINs` to other tables goes 'fast'.

In my experiment (with a different pair of tables), it touched only 5*15 rows.  I checked multiple versions; all seem to need this technique.  I used to he `Handler_reads` to verify the results.

When I tried with a `JOIN` but not a derived table, it was touching 2*N rows, where N was the number of rows without the `LIMIT`.

Comment: @billkarwin - If you are watching, what say you?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. All the things you said, everything is like that. Join could be causing the problem so I am thinking about running the query without the join and then use select * from apps where id IN() query to get additional data. I forgot what this method is called, used to solve n+1 problem. What do you think?

Comment: The new suggestion you provided is similar trick as I mentioned in my comment but your solution solves it in one query and less code. I will try that.